# How do universities verify qualifications?

Tags: university, degree

I want to apply for an academic job in the US or UK. I am curious how the universities verify my academic degrees. Do they call/write to my home university to verify my qualifications. In my home country, universities are not responsive to requests. Even, they do not ship the transcripts to employers (it's only available for pick up).

Can they reject my application because of no response from my university?

Answer (score 4):

For entry level positions (postdocs, visiting assistant professors, assistant professors), we usually start with letters of recommendations and copies of publications, including the thesis.

Usually one of the letter writers is the chair of the dissertation committee. That gives confidence that the dissertation is being completed or almost finished.

In one of my early jobs, I did have to send scans of my diplomas, but that was done after the job offer.

There's remarkably little authentication in academia. But that is likely because there is the perception that there is little outright credential fraud and because the consequences are so large.